# Why does the preterite of "traducir" transform into "tradujo"?

Tags: etimología, conjugación, tiempos-verbales, pretérito, formas-irregulares

As you will see below the preterite suffers from an odd transformation. Even native speakers make the mistake of conjugating the preterite of *traducir* wrong. For instance instead of *traduje* they mistakenly say *traducí*.

Present:

- Yo traduzco
- Tú traduces
- Él traduce
- Nosotros traducimos
- Ellos traducen

Preterite:

- Yo traduje
- Tú tradujiste
- Él tradujo
- Nosotros tradujimos
- Ellos tradujeron

Comment: Wow really? I've definitely been saying *traducí* :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason traces back to the Latin forms (and possibly farther back than that).  In Latin, duco/ducere "to lead" changes "c" to "x" (c+s = x) to form the perfect tense: [duxi, duxisti, duxit, ...](http://sphinx.metameat.net/latin.php?paradigm=duco)
This verb is the root of traducir, conducir, etc. Latin "x" normally corresponds with Spanish "j", hence conduje, condujiste, condujo, ....

Although most Spanish verbs are more regular, a few common irregular verbs still preserve this direct derivation of Latin perfect tense conjugations with unaccented personal endings -e, -iste, -o, -imos, -ieron, such as querer>quise, tener>tuve, estar>estuve, traer>traje, etc.

Comment: as a native Romanian, that would explain some things, in particular why the conjugation of "to be" is so close to "ser"

Answer (score 8):

"Traducir" is an irregular verb that follows the conjugation model of "conducir". In Spanish there are a few irregular verbs, some of them are completely irregular and others just partially.
 [At the conjugation site of Instituto de Verbología Hispánica](http://www.verbolog.com/conjuga.htm) you can find the 101 conjugation models in Spanish with the list of irregulars; and [this data base](http://www.verbolog.com/igca.htm) allows you to find any infinitive and indicates all the information about the verb you're looking for.

Comment: @Theta30 Is incorrect in English "flexion model"?

Comment: Yes, it is [incorrect](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=flexion). You can say "inflection", which in the case of verbs becomes "conjugation".

Comment: [Why shouldn't we use the word 'here' in a textlink](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12100/why-shouldnt-we-use-the-word-here-in-a-textlink)

Comment: @hippietrail edited and sorry :)

Comment: @Laura: Don't apologize but thanks for making your answer even better (-: